# How to make a java class related to another class with Neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a class `House` and a class `Room`.  Each of these classes are a `NodeEntity` and are persisted in separate repositories, `HouseRepository` and `RoomRepository`.  `House` contains a `Set<Room>`.  I want to be able to delete a `Room` instance and automatically have that instance removed from the `Set<Room>` inside of the `House` class.  Since Neo4j is a graph database, I figured that I should be able to declare a relationship between the `House` and each `Room` and deleting a `Room` instance will take care of this automatically.  The two following classes represent `House` and `Room`.

```
@NodeEntity
public class House {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Indexed(unique=true) String uid;

    @RelatedTo (type="addition", direction=Direction.OUTGOING)
    @Fetch
    private Set<Room> rooms;

    public House(String uid, Set<Room> rooms) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    public House() {
        this.uid = //random uid;
    }
}


@NodeEntity
public class Room {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Indexed(unique=true) String uid;

    public Room(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public Room() {
        this.uid = //random uid;
    }
}
```

I am thinking that I should be able to write a Cypher query in the `RoomRepository` that would take care of this, but I am not sure.  I have thought of something like this:

```
public interface RoomRepository extends BaseRepository<Room>{

    @Query("start room=node({0}) " +
            "match house-[:addition*]->room" +
            "delete room")
        public void deleteRoomAndRemoveRoomFromHouse(String uid);
}
```

What is the recommended way to handle these types of deletes?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: Have not got a compilable piece ready yet, but I am in the process of getting it ready to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach should almost work. You may bump up against an exception because you try to delete a node without first having deleted its relationship. (Unless SDN magic takes care of that for you, but I don't think it intercepts cypher queries.)

As your `MATCH` clause stands, it will act as a filter, meaning that whatever is bound to the `room` identifier in your start clause is only retained by the time you reach the `delete` clause if it has the relevant relationship of at least depth 1. If the room you pass as a parameter does not have at least one incoming `[:addition]` relationship, it is no longer bound and won't be deleted. Perhaps this is intentional, if so keep it, but add (otherwise replace it with) a match clause that binds all the rooms relationships and deletes them before you delete the room. Try something like

```
START room=node({0})
MATCH room-[r]-()
DELETE r, room
```

But I think either the repository or `Neo4jTemplate` should have plenty of voodoo to take care of this kind of operation for you. Or if you use the advanced mapping with `AspectJ`, you may have all kinds of chocolate chips baked into your `room` entity. I know there is a `NodeEntity#persist()`, I think there is a `NodeEntity#remove()` as well.

Once the node is deleted, it won't show up in the `Set<Room>` field of your room class. (If you use simple mapping you may have to retrieve it or sync it manually to the database, possibly a `Neo4jTemplate#fetch()`, passing the `Set<Room>` field, will do that for you.)

Comment: So, where would the use of `Neo4JTemplate#fetch(setOfRooms);` come into play so that it automatically updates the `Set<Room>` inside of the `House` class upon deletion?  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: In the simple mapping, the entity classes are detached from the database once populated, so there is no automatic update. But if you retrieve the entity with a repository lookup, or if you have it in a detached state and 'fetch' it, then the changes you have made to the database will be reflected. Delete the node, then 'fetch' or otherwise retrieve the entity class, and the change will be reflected.